# Почему не работает order в Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap

Как выровнять `col 13` по правому краю? - https://jsfiddle.net/q3r52ou1/

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ссылка на бутстрап альфа версии, а order появился в более поздних. И ещё в `bootstrap 4` нет `col-xs-*` есть просто `col-*`.

Вот то что ты хочешь реализовать на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3r52ou1/1/)